# How to create a fixed image video with ffmpeg that avoids pixelization when it's not maximized?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a waiting video in the project I develop. This video is a fixed waiting image with music. I was asked to change the image in the video due to deprecated logo.

So initially I tried just to replace the image in the video using this command:

```
ffmpeg -i old_waiting_video.mp4 -i new_image.png -filter_complex "[1][0]scale2ref[i][v];[v][i]overlay" -c:a copy new_waiting_video.mp4
```

This lead to the image became pixelated when the video isn't maximized. When maximized the image is OK. But it looks terrible in the small player.

Here is an image of the problem:

[image]

The above image is the image without zoom out. The left bottom image is a screen capture when I resize it in an image tool and the right bottom is a screen capture of how it looks like in the player.
The image has more than this text, but I thought that wouldn't be appropriate to display my company's logo here. The logo itself is even more pixelized and looks terrible.

So to try to solve this problem I extracted the audio from the file and try to add the image and the audio together to see if it removed the pixelization. So I used this command:

```
ffmpeg -i audio.m4a -i new_image.png new_waiting_video.mp4
```

When it failed, searching a bit I came across this other command:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i new_image.png -i audio.m4a -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -c:a copy -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest new_waiting_video.mp4
```

Again the pixelization ocurred. I know it's possible because this problem doesn't occur in the old logo.

What would be the correct command that allowed that the zoomed out image in the player doesn't pixelate ?

### Edit 1

I would also be interested in a command that substitutes the image on the old video as long it doesn't pixelate in the non-maximized player.

### Edit 2

- Video resolution: 1920x1080
- New image resolution: 1920x1080
- Non-maximized video player size: 640x360
- Video tag: `<video src="my-video-url.mp4" style="width: 640px;"></video>`

Comment: To the moderators: I put this question in SO because there is lots of active questions like this one and a specific ffmpeg tag. In case of this question is not adequate to this site please indicate the correct one on closing. Thanks.

Comment: I would submit that the jaggies will always happen on text edges if you have sharp edges in your image and you arbitrarily scale the video player. The easiest solution I can think of is to blur the edges of the text ever so slightly- perhaps use a gaussian blur.

Comment: Yes but the logo is pixelized also. And a blurred logo is out of question. Also that didn't happen in the old image which have the same text. There should be a way to do that.

Comment: Try replacing `-pix_fmt yuv420p` with `-pix_fmt yuv444p`. The overlay filter has an equivalent option (using new version of FFmpeg): `ffmpeg -i old_waiting_video.mp4 -i new_image.png -filter_complex "[1][0]scale2ref[i][v];[v][i]overlay:format=yuv444" -c:a copy -pix_fmt yuv444p new_waiting_video.mp4`. And, try using overlay without using `scale2ref` filter (scale the PNG image before using FFmpeg).

Comment: Replacing -pix_fmt yuv420p with -pix_fmt yuv444p resulted in the same pixelization. When trying with overlay filter I got the error No such filter: 'overlay:format' even after downloading the latest ffmpeg version (N-56320-ge937457b7b-static). 
And about scaling the image before using ffmpeg, AFAIU your suggestion scaling the image to a smaller format is not an option because I want the users to be able to maximize the browser and I need full resolution because of that.

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira I had a mistake, the syntax is `overlay=format=yuv444`. About scaling the image before using FFmpeg - try is just for testing. For testing, you may also display the video using a video player, viewing the video in 100% scaling mode without resizing. Keep in mind that resizing (scaling) an image always requires interpolation. There are selection of interpolation methods... What "image tool" are you using for creating the bottom left image?

Comment: I changed to overlay=format=yuv444 and the command worked but the pixelization continued. I tried to create a video with a resized (reduced size) image. As I expected, this way the small size was OK, but now when maximized the pixelization is far greater and it looks blurred. The image tool I'm using for scaling testing is Gimp with cubic interpolation.

Comment: "You may also display the video using a video player, viewing the video in 100% scaling mode without resizing" - I don't know if I understand what this means. Can you show an example ?

Comment: In VLC Player for example, remove the V from "Always Fit Window" and select Zoom "1:1 Original". [VLC Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLoUN.png). Use it in order to rule out the chance that your "video viewer" causes the pixelization issue. Note: In case you want to comment me please start your message with @Rotem.

Comment: @Rotem but that way the video enlarges and doesn't respect the window size. The original problem is that pixelization occurs in a non-maximized player. So I have to maintain the "Always Fit Window" option or I wouldn't simulate what happens in html video tag.

Comment: It looks like the pixelization occurs due to video player issue, and not related to FFmpeg. In case the video Player applies the same interpolation as GIMP (cubic interpolation), the  video supposed to be displayed fine (in case down-scaling the video, anti-aliasing filer may also required as part of the down-scaling). Can you please describe the way you are playing (rendering) the video? What is the resolution of the video? What is the resolution of the player's window? What is the resolution of the logo, before and after overlaying?

Comment: @Rotem Included the info in the question. Now, I included the new image resolution. I don't know what you mean by "resolution of the logo after overlaying". I imagine that "resolution of the logo BEFORE overlaying" is the resolution of the image. If it's not that could you please explain what it is ? Thanks. By the way, thanks for your continued help.

Comment: The resolution of the logo is 1920x1080? Never mind... The main issue is that I think that the video player is responsible for the pixelization (and that the issue is not related to FFmpeg). What video player are you using for displaying the 640x360 video?

Comment: Well actually I'm using Clappr (http://clappr.io/) but it happens with a normal html <video> tag also. So I guess it has nothing to do with Clappr itself. AFAIU it also has nothing to do with any internal workings of video tag because it happens equally in VLC.
Also the 640x360 resolution is the non-maximized size of the player not of the video. The video has 1980x1080 resolution.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue. I downloaded [new_image.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPqSA.png) from your post. I used the following command for creating 1920x1080 video (apply padding): `ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -i new_image.png -vf pad="w=1920:h=1080:x=(ow-iw)/2:y=(oh-ih)/2:color=white" -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -crf 10 -pix_fmt yuv444p -t 10 new_waiting_video.mp4`

Comment: With VLC I was unable to control the scaling interpolation, so I used FFplay. Nearest neighbor interpolation: `ffplay -i new_waiting_video.mp4 -vf scale=640x360:flags=neighbor`: [neighbor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1r0F.png) and lanczos interpolation: `ffplay -i new_waiting_video.mp4 -vf scale=640x360:flags=lanczos`: [lanczos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlCnI.png). [GIMP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6c7AG.png) quality still wins... I guess it's related to Anti-Aliasing filter.